# WMD's "live preview" functionality gets very jumpy when there's an image in the editor

Tags: bug, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [While making a post with an image, the image flickers in and out of the preview while I type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100557/while-making-a-post-with-an-image-the-image-flickers-in-and-out-of-the-preview)

[This video demonstrates what I'm talking about](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2011-12-14_1420.mp4)

I assume the flickering is caused by this sequence of events:

1. User keypresses in the WMD editor
2. There's an event bound to the keypress event that takes the WMD input, converts it to HTML, and replaces the existing HTML of `#wmd-preview` with the new HTML
3. The browser takes a split-second to re-display the image

Comment: The duplicate target question was deleted, and so was the video.